# Unhandled exception: The size of the state manager setting value has exceeded the limit

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Several of our customers see this unhandled exception that we never experience ourselves or were able to reproduce.

> Unhandled exception: The size of the state manager setting value has exceeded the limit  (Excep_FromHResult 0x80073DC8)

What can cause this exception?

Comment: From a quick google it appears to be related to storing things in local settings. You are very limited on the space in local settings and if you exceed that space you will need to serialize settings to a file in isolated storage.

Comment: We do not have any app setting that can cause an alarm, all of the mare either numbers or simple strings, no JSON or XML or any compound or complex values.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether they are complex or not. It's the volume not the complexity. You should verify that the settings aren't the issue though since in googling the exception you are getting that seemed to be the most common result - caused by settings being too large. Solution - store settings in a file in isolated storage.

Comment: I believe the exception means the the specific setting value is too large not the total number of settings or combined setting value is too large.

Answer (score 10):

`LocalSettings` do have some limits, see the **Remarks** section in [ApplicationData.LocalSettings | localSettings property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings):

> The name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most. Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting can be up to 64K bytes in size.

When the size of the setting is too large, it will raise this exception. Although there is no general size restriction on the total number of settings, it's better to store large data sets to files in isolated storage. So like @pstrjds said, you may need to verify the size of the settings in your app and if some of them could be large, you may try to store them in `LocalFolder`.

Answer (score 3):

Did some tests on Universal Windows application and discovered that each property value must not exceed 4095 bytes in size. So the following code will fix it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Application settings
/// Limit to 200*4095
/// </summary>
private const string SET_STR = "SETTINGS";
private const int CHUNK_SIZE = 4095;
static private ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
static private string AppSettings {
    get {
        string set = "";
        for (int i = 0;i < 200;i++) {
            string s = (string)localSettings.Values[SET_STR + i];
            if (s != null) {
                set += s;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
    set {
        for (int i = 0;i < 200;i++) {
            localSettings.Values[SET_STR + i] = null;
        }
        for (int i = 0;i * CHUNK_SIZE < value.Length;i++) {
            if (value.Length > i * CHUNK_SIZE) {
                int len = (i + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE > value.Length ? value.Length % CHUNK_SIZE : CHUNK_SIZE;
                localSettings.Values[SET_STR + i] = value.Substring(i * CHUNK_SIZE, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```